# Error waiting for a debug connection: Bad state: No element Flutter VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Updated vscode today after that created new flutter projects are showing error
***Error waiting for a debug connection: Bad state: No element***
`Error waiting for a debug connection: Bad state: No element`

Comment: If you get a stack trace in the error (or a log file generated with a stack trace in it), please include that.

Comment: updating to newest vscode solved the issue for me

Comment: VS Code Updating solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have to try a clean project and it's work for me

```
flutter clean
```